# udev held back by apt-get while using ondrej systemd PPA

Tags: apt, udev

For probably about a month now, `udev` has been held back by `apt-get` when running `apt-get updgrade`.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 udev : Depends: sysv-rc (>= 2.88dsf-24) but 2.88dsf-13.10ubuntu11.1 is to be installed or
                 file-rc (>= 0.8.16) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I thought it might go away eventually as packages were updated, but as I said, it's been about a month now. I'm wondering if someone might have some insight on why I can't update this package (I tried googling, but my google-fu on this problem is a little weak).

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, and this is on a server-type machine (no GUI).

I have the following PPA's on my system:

- [~nijel/phpmyadmin](https://launchpad.net/~nijel/+archive/phpmyadmin)
- [~ondrej/apache2](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/apache2)
- [~ondrej/debhelper](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/debhelper)
- [~ondrej/mysql](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/mysql)
- [~ondrej/php5](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5)
- [~ondrej/systemd](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/systemd)
- [~svn/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~svn/+archive/ppa)
- [~rwky/redis](https://launchpad.net/~rwky/+archive/redis)

And also the [Postgres Apt Repository](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt). I looked through them all, and didn't see any of the packages above being provided by these PPA's, but I thought I would mention it.

Comment: @Braiam, when I run those two commands, nothing happens (`apt-get` runs successfully, and there is no output for the `dpkg` command). See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6589966)

Comment: @EliahKagan as can be seen in the answer, the problem is the PPA's maintainer fault. None of those answers will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the [ondrej/systemd](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/systemd/+packages) ppa.

If you expand the [package files for precise](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/systemd/+packages), you'll see the ppa is providing `sysv-rc`.

Moreover, the main page says the `[ppa] follows latest systemd packages as maintained by Debian systemd team.`

Look at the [package details in Debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=sysv-rc) and you'll see the `apt` is looking for a Debian-style name; but it's odd that `apt` is proposing the standard, non-ppa package.

Maybe the ppa needs to re-configured or re-installed; or perhaps you should file a bug against the ppa.

Comment: I meant to come back and answer with a similar answer... the PPA owner must have fixed the package, it was able to be updated as of a few weeks ago.